# How do I increment an attribute at runtime using getattr/setattr?

Tags: python

I have a class with ten different counters. I need to increment one or another of these at runtime, and the increment method is told the name of the counter to increment.

I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way than this:

```
def increment(self, name):
    """Increments a counter specified by the 'name' argument."""
    setattr(self, name, getattr(self, name) + 1)
```

- I'm not terribly worried about race conditions and the like.
- No, you can't change the way the function is called. Obviously, the real code is a little less trivial than the example.

Comment: Would it be possible to have a dictionary of names to counters?

Comment: As noted in comments on answers below -- no, you do not have a dictionary of counters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could store the counters in a dictionary instead of in attributes.

Alternatively, you could use

```
def increment(self, name):
    """Increments a counter specified by the 'name' argument."""
    self.__dict__[name] += 1
```

It's up to you to decide if this is "cleaner".

Comment: I can't change how the counters are stored; they're fields in a django model. The `__dict__` trick is nice, though.

Comment: Of course, having the counters in `<obj>.__dict__` *is* storing them in a dictionary.

Comment: Well, touching `__dict__` feels rather dirty, but it sounds like it's the only alternative to get/setattr in this case. Thanks for the suggestion, though!